# Getting error (numpy.ndarray not callable) in Finding derivative of Sigmoid function

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to neutral network & was trying to find derivative of sigmoid function.please help me to fix this error.
My code is like;

import numpy as np

def sigmoid_derivative(x):

```
a=1/np.exp(x) +1

s=1/a

ds=s(1-s) 

return ds
```

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])

print ("sigmoid_derivative(x) = " + str(sigmoid_derivative(x)))

Output:Error, numpy.ndarray is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you got the sigmoid function wrong.

What I suggest is something like :

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))


def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
```

Here's a link that would help you understand better: [Derivative of the Sigmoid function](https://towardsdatascience.com/derivative-of-the-sigmoid-function-536880cf918e)

Answer (score 0):

on line `ds=s(1-s)` you are calling numpy.ndarray s with parameter 1-s, I think you need `ds=s * (1-s)`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a multiplication operator:

```
ds= s * (1-s)
```